# Azure Function Kudu (SCM) failing to start

Tags: azure, function

Having tried multiple times to restart the function the SCM (Kudu) instance fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE pointing to a file share that did not exist.

Comment: Also noticed Terraform was setting the WEBSITE_CONTENTSHAR to a file share that didn't exist.